# How to conditionally add middleware in another middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm wondering how I can add middleware conditionally in another middleware in my Laravel project.

I noticed that Laravel Nova adds middleware in this way in the `NovaCoreServiceProvider`

```
$this->app->make(HttpKernel::class)->pushMiddleware(ServeNova::class);
```

I am trying to accomplish this outside of the scope of a service provider, where you do not have access to `$this->app`, so I tried it this way:

```
$container = app();
$container->make(HttpKernel::class)->pushMiddleware(MyMiddleware::class);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to push middleware to the stack from a middleware? If so, how can I accomplish this?

The only reason I am doing it this way as opposed to just simply registering it normally is to prevent the unnecessary loading of resources (which the middleware is responsible for triggering).

Comment: "outside of the scope of a service provider"

Where are you doing this?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson another middleware

Comment: IIRC you won't be able to do this. The middleware runs through a pipeline and you can't add additional middleware steps to that pipeline while it is running. I think the only way you can push middleware to the middleware stack is through a service provider which is run before Laravel handles an incoming request.

Comment: @GeorgeHanson Ahh okay that does make sense and is kind of what I figured. Thank you!